# Migration project of worksheet functions and VBA modules in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, migration, worksheet-function

**Background:**
I am currently working on a migration project of a large excel workbook (1 sheet of raw data and about 60 sheets of tables and graphs generated from the data).

The sheets are generated by a mix of methods from both worksheet functions and VBA modules in Excel.
The mehods in VBA are standard stuff (loops, if statements, classes, sub methods, functions etc.).

**Goal:** My task is to migrate as much as possible (preferably all) of the methods to one place. 
I.e. making all the methods into VBA modules or into worksheet functions inserted in all of the worksheets.

All of this will in the future once again be migrated, but this time to C#. The current migration is meant to be a preperation for this step.

The goal of migration is to collect all method into one place. This will improve the structure, making it easier to get an overwiew of the excel workbook.

**My main question is**: What is the smartest option to migrate the methods into, VBA modules or as worksheet functions?

Is it even possible to migrate everything to worksheets function?
What are the limits of worksheet function contra VBA modules?

Please give me feedback if you need further clarifications about the task.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you really want to move everything to a single location then VBA rather than WSF seems like the answer, since not everything which can be done in VBA can be done in a WSF.  This is still one of those "it depends" questions though: not really a good fit for SO.

Comment: How do you mean with "it depends"? As I see it, WSF gives quick results for simple operations and nothing other than that. Would you agree? Thank you for the reply.

Comment: "it depends" means your question does not include all the info required to make a fully-informed judgment about what the "best" thing to do is. Without knowing much more detail about exactly what the function of the workbook is, who is using it, the relative strengths of the people involved in adapting it, what the "migration" to C# is intended to get you, etc, etc, any answers are only guesses.  The main issue is that your question presents an either/or scenario when the best approach in excel is to use both VBA and WSF, *where appropriate*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, worksheet functions cannot do everything that is possible in VBA, so i would most likely suggest that you go towards the vba route.  The worksheet functions are generally relatively easy to convert to VBA code(as you can record a macro, not the neatest, fastest way, but gets the job done).  I would especially look to going to vba if you have an unknown number of rows or columns in the spreadsheet (If the data is changing that is), so you can use stuff such as lastrow and lastcolumn so you don't have to keep changing formula ranges and such.